# Фон перекрывает выделенный мышкой текст

Tags: html, css, css3, веб-дизайн

В общем, в одной проге(obsidian) я юзаю одну тему(molecule.css). И вот в этой теме серый фон внутри блока `` перекрывает выделение текста. С чем это может быть связано, как исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код css: https://pastebin.com/wSii6TUC
Вот какие селекторы отвечают за это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Не могу сказать точно, мог бы сказать точнее если бы вы дали ссылку на сайт. Но скорее всего вам просто нужно убрать background, мб не в этом месте, посмотрите на все background которые есть, поэкспериментируйте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не сайт, а приложение obsidian.md. Дело в том, что фон мне нужен, но он не должен перекрывать выделение текста.